# Integrating and deriving absolute functions sympy

Tags: python, sympy, integral, derivative, calculus

Sympy is generally a great tool for calculating both the integral and derivative of a function. When the function happens to contain an absolute component though (|x|), for some reason it doesn't seem to be able to figure that out.

when for example you write something like this:

`diff(abs(x+1))`

you'll get the following output:

`sign⁡(x+1)`

The answer shoud be **(x+1)/|x+1|**, so is there something wrong with sympy and is there a way around it?

Comment: In sympy `sign(z)` is defined as `z/|z|` for all non-zero complex `z`

Comment: Alrtight, and is there a way you can convert it to z/[z]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SymPy `sign(z)` is defined as `z/|z|` for complex non-zero `z`. In fact another definition of `sign(z)` is precisely as the derivative of `abs(z)`:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Definition

It should ideally be possible to use `rewrite(Abs)` with `sign` but is not currently:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19277

Note that rewrite wouldn't work in your case without any way to know that `x+1` is nonzero (e.g. if `x` is declared as positive`).

You can force the rewrite manually using `replace` though:

```
In [4]: s
Out[4]: sign(x + 1)

In [5]: s.replace(sign, lambda arg: arg/Abs(arg))
Out[5]: 
 x + 1 
───────
│x + 1│
```